# Is it possible to get webpack-dev-server to ignore all but a certain path in the proxy settings?

Tags: proxy, webpack-dev-server

I've got my WDS running on port `9000`, and the webpack bundles located under `/dist/`  I've got a back end server running on port `55555`

Is there a way to get WDS to ignore (proxy to `55555`) every call *except* those starting with `/dist/`?

I've got the following:

```
  devServer: {
    port: 9000,
    proxy: {
      "/dist": "http://localhost:9000",
      "/": "http://localhost:55555"
    }
  }
```

Trouble is, that root ("/") just overrides *everything*...

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

UPDATE:
I've gotten a little farther with the following:

```
proxy: {
    "/": {
        target: "http://localhost:55555",
        bypass: function(req, res, proxyOptions) {
            return (req.url.indexOf("/dist/") !== -1);
        }
    }
},
```

But the bypass just seems to kill the connection.  I was hoping it would tell the (9000) server to not proxy when the condition is true.  Anybody know a good source explaining "bypass"?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack allows glob syntax for these patterns. As a result, you should be able to use an exclusion to match "all-but-dist".

Something like this may work (sorry I don't have webpack in front of me at the moment):

```
devServer: {
  port: 9000,
  proxy: {
    "!/dist/**/*": "http://localhost:55555"
  }
}
```